# How to add styling and links to manual WordPress excerpt

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've hit a bit of a road block I'm not sure how to add font styling i.e. bold font and also links.

I'm trying to get something like what brian over at backlinko has, which can be seen in this image below
[image]

I've only managed to achieve this:
[image]

Any ideas or suggestion to be able to achieve adding links and font styling to WordPress manual excerpt would be brilliant.

Comment: which part of it do you need help with? can you not add an anchor tag and or do you need suggestions on how to style it...? what is your question?

Comment: ...or are you maybe looking for [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt)...?

Comment: @webeno thanks I figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was totally overthinking this and thought it was more complex than it actually was.

All I had to do was write the HTML inline in the manual excerpt box like this:

```
People that succeed with launching a new blog do one thing very well:

They build an email list! But in most cases, they do this before even launching their blog.

But you're probably wondering:

"How do I build an email list before I've even launched my blog?"

I'll break it down into three simple actionable steps that you implement yourself.

[alert-note]<strong>Free Checklist:</strong><a href="a">Download a free checklist</a> that shows you exactly how to use the strategy from this post (step-by-step).[/alert-note]
```